# two blocks of code give different results

Tags: javascript

Why these two blocks of code give different results? This first block of code is returning false it seems but second block of code is working properly. In the first block I've even printed value of all boolean operations which are all true but still it is returning false.

```
return
    mm_card_type_flag &&
                    mm_mm_flag &&
                    mm_yyyy_flag &&
                    $('#hdfccc .' + 'card_no').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_number &&
                    $('#hdfccc .' + 'cvv_no').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_cvv &&
                    $('#hdfccc .' + 'card_name').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_name &&
                    $("#hdfccc .ignorebank").prop('checked') == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.ignorebank &&
                    $("#hdfccc .password").val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.password &&
                    $('#hdfccc input[name="acsRadio"]:checked').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.radio_val &&
                    $("#hdfcc-secure-pin").val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_secure_pin &&
                    $("#hdfccc .prevent-toofast-c").prop('checked') == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.prevent_too_fast_c;
```

**AND**

```
var ret = mm_card_type_flag &&
                    mm_mm_flag &&
                    mm_yyyy_flag &&
                    $('#hdfccc .' + 'card_no').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_number &&
                    $('#hdfccc .' + 'cvv_no').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_cvv &&
                    $('#hdfccc .' + 'card_name').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_name &&
                    $("#hdfccc .ignorebank").prop('checked') == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.ignorebank &&
                    $("#hdfccc .password").val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.password &&
                    $('#hdfccc input[name="acsRadio"]:checked').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.radio_val &&
                    $("#hdfcc-secure-pin").val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_secure_pin &&
                    $("#hdfccc .prevent-toofast-c").prop('checked') == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.prevent_too_fast_c;

    return ret;
```

**Full function**

```
function hdfccc_options_iSame()
    {
        var mm_card_type_flag = true;
        var mm_mm_flag = true;
        var mm_yyyy_flag = true;

        if (user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_card_type)
            {
                mm_card_type_flag = ($('#hdfccc .' + 'card_type').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_card_type);
            }

        if (user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_mm)
            {
                mm_mm_flag = ($('#hdfccc .' + 'card_expiry_mon').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_mm);
            }

        if (user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_yyyy)
            {
                mm_yyyy_flag = ($('#hdfccc .' + 'card_expiry_year').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_yyyy);
            }

            console.log

( mm_card_type_flag ,
                mm_mm_flag ,
                mm_yyyy_flag ,
                $('#hdfccc .' + 'card_no').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_number ,
                $('#hdfccc .' + 'cvv_no').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_cvv ,
                $('#hdfccc .' + 'card_name').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_name ,
                $("#hdfccc .ignorebank").prop('checked') == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.ignorebank ,
                $("#hdfccc .password").val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.password ,
                $('#hdfccc input[name="acsRadio"]:checked').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.radio_val ,
                $("#hdfcc-secure-pin").val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_secure_pin ,
                $("#hdfccc .prevent-toofast-c").prop('checked') == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.prevent_too_fast_c);


       var ret=
        mm_card_type_flag &&
                mm_mm_flag &&
                mm_yyyy_flag &&
                $('#hdfccc .' + 'card_no').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_number &&
                $('#hdfccc .' + 'cvv_no').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_cvv &&
                $('#hdfccc .' + 'card_name').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_name &&
                $("#hdfccc .ignorebank").prop('checked') == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.ignorebank &&
                $("#hdfccc .password").val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.password &&
                $('#hdfccc input[name="acsRadio"]:checked').val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.radio_val &&
                $("#hdfcc-secure-pin").val() == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.mm_secure_pin &&
                $("#hdfccc .prevent-toofast-c").prop('checked') == user_selections.mm_hdfccc_details.prevent_too_fast_c;


        return ret;

    }
```

Comment: Cause JS is stupid :D In first variant your code returns empty string.

Comment: make `return` and `mm_card_type_flag ` in same line.

Comment: So, "return" work with line on that it written.

Comment: this is one place JS shouldn't be thinking *"oh, silly user forgot the `;` after return, I'll pretend it's there anyway"*

Comment: @JaromandaX I need some memonic  so that I don't fall in this trap again and recognize this easily next time. I work on C++/Java/PHP/Javascript. So this is difficult to remember.

Comment: Yeah. I always use ; . Problem is that this is one time javascript makes life hard.  A jd linter could help

Comment: running tools like eslint will warn you of things like this.  It would tell you that the next line is unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript compiler treats

```
return
    true
```

as

```
return ''; // returns ''
 true      // can't be reached!
```

you can split the comparator up over multiple lines but there must be something immediately after the return

```
return true &&
         false  // returns false
```